# PyQt4 QSqlTableModel, QTableView intermittent update

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt4

I have a very strange bug that I can't seem to diagnose.

I have a PyQt4 application that uses a QSqlTableModel to display data in a QTableView.  I have repeated the bug in an isolated program as follows.  When I run the program, most of the cells/columns are editable and change the database.  However, for some reason (when I run it this time) the 5th row is not editable.  The problematic row seems to change.

Are there any suggestions on how to debug this further?  I have overridden the setData method and it is behaving as expected.  It passes the new value, and the parent setData returns True; however, the database doesn't change and the tableView reverts back to the old data.

**EDIT**: Suspecting that this could be a PyQt4 bug, I installed the latest PyQt4 (version 4.10).  This doesn't not seem to change the behavior of the problem.  I also noticed that I didn't include my database class.  I've updated the code listing to also include the DB class. It is pulling the database connection info from a config file.  Basically, it is just using a MySQL5 server backend.

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        print "Opening database connection."
        self.data = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
        self.data.setHostName(parent.config.get('Database','mysql_server'))
        self.data.setPort(int(parent.config.get('Database','mysql_port')))
        self.data.setDatabaseName(parent.config.get('Database','mysql_database'))
        self.data.setUserName(parent.config.get('Database','mysql_user'))
        self.data.setPassword(parent.config.get('Database','mysql_pass'))

        if not self.data.open() :
            print "error opening database"
            print self.data.lastError().text()

        print "database init complete"


class Model(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):

    def __init__(self, prjID, parent = None):
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnRowChange)

        self.setTable("Debug")


        self.setFilter("PrjID = " + str(prjID))

        if not self.select() :
            print "error, ", self.lastError().text()




class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow) :
    def __init__(self) :
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read("default.cfg")
        self.db = Database(self)
        self.model = Model(39,self)        
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(0,0,4000,400)


        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Main()  #QtGui.QMainWindow()
    #ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    #ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the debug table I created.  As you can see above, my backend DB is MySQL.  Could I perhaps be doing something wrong with the way I'm defining this table?:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Debug` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PrjID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WorkType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Qty` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `UnitCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Note` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShowDetail` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `SubTotal` float DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=101 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Debug`
--

INSERT INTO `Debug` (`ID`, `PrjID`, `WorkType`, `Qty`, `UnitCost`, `Note`, `ShowDetail`, `SubTotal`) VALUES
(1, 37, 10, 66, 1, 'asdfasdf', 1, 66),
(2, 37, 7, 22, 2, 'asdfasdf', 1, 44),
(3, 37, 11, 11, 33, 'asdfasdf', 1, 363),
(4, 37, 7, 1, 10, 'asdfasdf', 1, 10),
(5, 37, 10, NULL, NULL, 'aa', 0, NULL),
(100, 39, 6, 8, 10, 'aa', 0, 80),
(6, 38, 10, 2151, 0.20000000298, NULL, 0, 430.2),
(7, 38, 27, 120.25, 0, '123', 1, 0),
(8, 38, 22, 5.69, 5, NULL, 0, 28.45),
(9, 38, 7, 3, 35, NULL, 1, 105),
(11, 39, 1, 6, 35, 'aa', 0, 210),
(12, 39, 17, 17.78842, 6.5, 'zz', 0, 115.625),
(13, 39, 27, 147.944803, 0, 'zz', 0, 0),
(14, 39, 28, 82.17064, 15, NULL, 0, 1232.56),
(15, 39, 30, 64.42334, 0, 'aa', 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Explaination:** Few more things that I have figured out.  I think my basic problem is that my table does not define a primary key.  When I create the table with a PRIMARY KEY instead of UNIQUE KEY, the problem goes away.

As far as PyQt4 goes, I have also learned that I need to hide columns (such as ID column) by using the QTableView's setColumnHidden method and not the QSqlTableModel's removeColumn.  Once the ID column (primary key) is removed, then the updates get screwy.

I've also determined that if I'm using a view (granted that view has to be editable as required by MySQL), that I have to manually set the primary key in the QSqlTableModel.  For example:

```
pk = QtSql.QSqlIndex("cursName","idxName")
pk.append(QtSql.QSqlField("ID"))
self.setPrimaryKey(pk)
```