# QSqlTableModel setPrimaryKey for a mysql view

Tags: qt

I have a QSqlTableModel that works to view/update a table in mysql.  If I make a view of the table then it will display the data but edits fail.  I can update the table with a mysql update so the view is updateable.

I think what is happening is that since the view does not have a primary key the primary key for the QSqlTableModel is not set and it won't update.

I can't find any examples how to set the primary key.  The setPrimaryKey() of QSqlTableModel is protected.  I am sure I am missing something fundamental but searching returns a lot of results for view in the context of MVC.

Can anyone point me to an example of how to call setPrimaryKey or an example of using a QSqlTableModel to update a database view in mysql?

Comment: There is this similar answer for pyqt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262614/pyqt4-qsqltablemodel-qtableview-intermittent-update

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking now that this is not going to work like I want it to anyway.  I could probably make it work for a view with a single table but it would likely be too much work to make it behave properly if I have a view with multiple tables.  It would be better to take a different approach.